# Time required to complete same work by more people

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If 45 people can built a pyramid in 288 days, how many days would it take 65 people to build the next 1/6 the pyramid, rounded to nearest integer, assuming each person works at the same constant rate?

Solution:  as their rate are same i used the equation-

$$w=nrt$$
or, $$(1/2)w = 45 \cdot r \cdot 288$$

and $$w'=n'rt'= 65 \cdot r \cdot t'$$

or,$$(1/6) \cdot (1/2) \cdot w = 65 \cdot r \cdot t'$$

or, $$(1/2) \cdot w= 6 \cdot 65 \cdot r \cdot t'$$

From two equations, $45 \cdot 288=6 \cdot 65 \cdot t'$,

i.e,  $t'= 33$ days (approximately).

But, the actual answer is showing $66$ days instead of $33$ days. In 2nd part it is written as, $\frac16 w$ instead of $(\frac16) \cdot \frac{w}{2}$. Why? does next $\frac16$ the pyramid mean $\frac16$ of the pyramid? or it means $\frac16$ of the remaining pyramid?

Comment: Please use MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: thank you very much, i was looking for this

Comment: Even if you don't know MathJax, at least check the preview before pushing the Post button. You would have found that your formulas run together and become completely unreadable ...

Comment: I calculated that if the whole population of Egypt worked together (including children, babies and women), they would build a pyramid in `0.006 s`!

Comment: @Bernard What about the aliens? Don't they help out anymore?

Comment: @LOvsovs: Aliens, of course… But in these times of Olympic Games, I prefer to highlight the feats mankind can achieve ;o)

Comment: Of course the next pyramid takes much longer to build, as the nearby quarry was used up by the first pyramid, and therefore the stones must be brought from a quarry much farther away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is correct, since we have 
\begin{align}p&=45\times 288\\
\frac{1}{6}p&=65\times t \\
\Rightarrow t &\approx 33
\end{align}
So either the question is poorly worded, or the result given in the book (or wherever the question was taken from) is wrong (which happens more often than you might think).